# Django application slow due to multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble displaying and modeling in django with multiple foreign keys.

When displaying or creating it takes a long time as I have a lot of data.

For example when trying to create with CreateView it takes a long time, or when trying to display the stored data.

Is there any way to optimize the creation and at the time of display?

The models with multiple foreging key and ManyToManyField are the following:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Nombre", max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Socio, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="player_socio")
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="player_division", blank=True, null=True)
    goals = models.IntegerField("Goles", default=0)
    league = models.ForeignKey("League", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="player_league")
```

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team = models.CharField("Equipo", max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    league = models.ForeignKey("League", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="team_league", blank=True, null=True)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, blank=True, related_name="player_team")
```

```
class Match(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey(League, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="match_league")
    date = models.DateField("Fecha", default=timezone.now)
    week = models.IntegerField("Semana", default=0)
    team_1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="team_1_goal")
    team_2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="team_2_goal")
```

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    goal = models.IntegerField("Goles", default=0)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, 
    related_name="match_goals")
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, 
    related_name="player_goal")
    league = models.ForeignKey("League", on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name="player_league_goal")
```

And when creating or displaying the data I use class-based views.

I tried to display the data with select2 but it's still slow.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

use prefetch_related and select_related queryset for enhancing performance

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prefetch_related-and-select_related-functions-in-django/